# Error compiling dlib on os x

Tags: python, c++, cmake, dlib

I'm trying to compile dlib on my computer (OS X 10.10) but am running into an error I'm not sure how to fix. When I run CMake I get this output

```
Configuring cmake ...
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 7.0.0.7000176
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 7.0.0.7000176
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Could NOT find Boost
-- Boost version: 1.59.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonLibs: Found unsuitable version "2.7.10", but required
  is at least "3.4" (found PYTHON_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:386 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake:205 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/dlib/add_python_module:64 (FIND_PACKAGE)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/tools/python/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
error: cmake configuration failed!
```

First of all I'm wondering how CMake could not find Boost but then in the next line give the version of boost I currently have installed on my computer? Second, I'm wondering how I go about fixing the pythonlibs error? I've tried Googling around but mainly have just found other people with similar errors but not what it means or how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Maybe CMake *did* find boost, but it determined that it couldn't find a *suitable* version and that's why it said "Could NOT find Boost" and then gave you the version it found so you had a chance to figure out what was wrong (since you clearly have boost installed). I think the real problem might be your python version -- to me, the error message below the boost version stuff, suggest you have python 2.7.10 but you need 3.4 to compile dlib.

Comment: Boost has several components (libraries) and you can mark some requried. So Boost in general is found, but not the required boost-python error. First fix the problem with the outdated python. If you have Python 3 already installed, pass the right flags to CMake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that your boost installed with python 3?If so, I suggest you to set your default python version 3.x, or reinstall boost with the current python version like this:

```
To compile Boost.Python yourself download boost from boost.org and then go into the boost root folder and run these commands:
./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=python
./b2
sudo ./b2 install
```

I've solved the problem **Could NOT find Boost** with the above solution.